# Creating a for-loop to store LDA misclassification rates

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, pca, tibble

I have a dataset of 104 samples (2 classes) and 182 variables. I am to carry out LDA on the dataset. My strategy involves first carrying out PCA in order to reduce dimensionality; this leaves me with 104 PCs. Now, what I want to do is carry out LDA on the PCs. I want to carry it out first where the number of PCs equal to 1, and store the misclassification rates into a data frame object. I will then do the same for 2, 3 and so on until ~50 PCs; the number is not important. I have created a for-loop to try solve this but I end up with a data frame where the only row is the final value I choose for my PCs. Here is the code I have so far:

```
# required packages
library(MASS)
library(class)
library(tidyverse)

# reading in and cleaning data
og_data <- read.csv("data.csv")
og_data <- og_data[, -1]
og_data$tumour <- unclass(as.factor(og_data$tumour))

# standardizing
st_data <- as.data.frame(cbind(og_data[, 1], scale(og_data[, -1])))
colnames(st_data)[1] <- "tumour"

# PCA for dimension reduction
k=10                                             # this is for the for-loop
grouping <- c(rep(1, 62), rep(2, 42))            # a vector denoting the true class of the samples
pca <- prcomp(st_data[, -1])

df_misclassification <- tibble(i=as.numeric(), 
                               misclassification_rate_1=as.numeric(), 
                               misclassification_rate_2=as.numeric())

for (i in k){
  a <- as.data.frame(pca$x[, 1:i])
  b <- lda(a, grouping=grouping, CV=TRUE)
  c <- table(list(predicted=b$class, observed=grouping)) # confusion matrix
  d <- t(as.data.frame(diag(c) / rowSums(c)))            # misclassification rate for each class
  df_misclassification <- df_misclassification %>%
    add_row(i=i, 
            misclassification_rate_1=d[, 1], 
            misclassification_rate_2=d[, 2])
}
```

Running the above for `k=10` leaves me with the following data frame:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
      i misclassification_rate_1 misclassification_rate_2
  <dbl>                    <dbl>                    <dbl>
1    10                    0.952                    0.951
```

I would like the table to have 10 rows, one for each number of PCs used. There is some overwriting in the for-loop but I have no idea how to fix this. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My for-loop was wrong. It should have been `for (i in 1:k)`.